# Switch camera access between AR Foundation and (Android) Native

Tags: unity-game-engine, augmented-reality, android-camera2, android-camerax, ar-foundation

I've been trying to develop an app, that would guide the user through an environment via AR. Basically, the user's goal is to capture images in some environment, and the app should help with image alignment, show missing spots etc.

The video feed in AR is, by default, of quite a low resolution. So I thought I would develop my own android (ios coming next...) plugin that would access the camera in the background, take the picture and save it. I've had some success with this, images look crisp and are of default resolution (as if used by the native app). However, the AR feed then lags for almost 5 seconds, which is too long.

I am using Unity and AR Foundation (mostly cross-platform reasons).

For the plugin I am building an Android library (.aar), importing it into Unity and then using the Unity toolset to call the android classes.

When I tried using the NativeCamera asset, there was no lag after a successful capture. As this asset basically spawns the camera intent though, it is not usable.

Then I tried using Logcat to see what I might have missed.

Two errors usually arise:

in all of the cases:

```
Session 0: Exception while stopping repeating: android.hardware.camera2.CameraAccessException: CAMERA_ERROR (3): cancelRequest:688: Camera 0: Error clearing streaming request: Function not implemented (-38)
```

and sometimes:

```
CameraAccessException: CAMERA_DISCONNECTED (2): checkPidStatus:2274: The camera device has been disconnected
```

This is what Logcat registered during the lag period:

[Loglag](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SkIcY.png)

I've been trying to use both CameraX and Camera2 to achieve this, looking all over the internet to find some basic workable snippets that could be expanded.

The Camera2 implementation I am experimenting with now is basically a stripped down and slightly edited https://gist.github.com/RoundSparrow/142b840ca86ba7a46639f23c5c0d195b .
I've changed mainly the capture mode from repeating to single capture:
`.createCaptureRequest(CameraDevice.TEMPLATE_STILL_CAPTURE)`
and
`session.capture()`

Anything that I am missing or is it impossible to pull something like this off?